# Is it possible to extend trained Neural Network to recognize additional patterns

Tags: neural-network

Lets say I have Neural Network (NN) that is trained to recognize cats given an image, is there a way to update my NN to recognize dogs as well?
More generally, my question is regarding a way to extend a NN by kind a "loading patterns library".

Comment: Look at adaptive resonance theory ;)

Comment: thanks, interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally known as transfer learning, you basically train a neural network on a large dataset (like ImageNet) and then use the feature vector that is generated by the final convolutional layer to train another classifier (a multiclass SVM for example), and this works even if the objects are different.

Another way is to take a pretrained network and retrain the classifier part (the fully connected layers). It is still faster than training a network from scratch.